# Web Audio API on iOS Safari do not play even after user interaction

Tags: ios, html, audio, safari

I know that there is a limitation in iOS Safari where the audio is not playing until user triggers an interaction. So I have placed the code inside a `touchstart` event. But unfortunately, I have tried almost every combination, and I couldn't get it to play on iOS Safari.

Here are the things I have tried:

- putting the audio load outside the `touchstart` callback
- try adding a gain node
- use 0.01 as the start time

and none of the above works in iOS Safari, but they can all play in desktop Chrome and Safari. Here is the link to the gist, you can see the versions where I made the changes (P.S. the click event is used for testing on desktop)

https://gist.github.com/angelathewebdev/32e0fbd817410db5dea1

Answer (score 0):

Sounds play only when currentTime starts to run, but scheduling sounds exactly at currentTime doesn't seem to work. They need to be a little bit into the future (ex: 10ms). You can use the following createAudioContext function to wait until the context is ready to make noise. User action doesn't seem to be required on iPhone, but no such success on iPad just yet.

```
function createAudioContext(callback, errback) {
    var ac = new webkitAudioContext();
    ac.createGainNode(); // .. and discard it. This gets 
                         // the clock running at some point.

    var count = 0;

    function wait() {
        if (ac.currentTime === 0) {
            // Not ready yet.
            ++count;
            if (count > 600) {
                errback('timeout');
            } else {
                setTimeout(wait, 100);
            }
        } else {
            // Ready. Pass on the valid audio context.
            callback(ac); 
        }
    }

    wait();
}
```

Subsequently, when playing a note, don't call .noteOn(ac.currentTime), but do .noteOn(ac.currentTime + 0.01) instead.